# Blender 2.8 transparency & volumetrics?

Tags: transparency, eevee-render-engine

Can somebody walk me through the process of getting volumetrics and transparency working in EEVEE.
I recently hopped on from 2.79 but all my glasswork just isnt working.
I tried all the alpha channels and spent a lot of time searching but i can't find the thing im missing or doing wrong.
Included is a simple set-up that works in 2.79/2.80 cycles but not in 2.80 EEVEE.

[image: 2.79 cycles]
[image: 2.80 EEVEE]
[image: Material of transparent object]

Answer (score 2):

Answer has been found here.
https://blenderartists.org/t/transparent-materials-workflow-from-cycles-to-eevee-from-2-79/1129207/5

TL;DR
Enable screen space refractions in your material under options.
Leave blend mode on opaque.
Ënable screen space reflections in your render settings under screen space reflection.